# How can I display the count of a specific field on the Crud::PAGE_INDEX page

Tags: symfony, count, query-builder, easyadmin

Is there a way to add aggregation data, such as the count or sum of a specific field, to the EasyAdmin 'index' (Crud::PAGE_INDEX) page with a separate column?

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable {

    yield IdField::new('id');
    yield TextField::new('mycount');

}
```

```
public function createIndexQueryBuilder(): QueryBuilder {

    $queryBuilder->addSelect('COUNT(entity.id) AS HIDDEN mycount'); 
    return $queryBuilder; 
}
```